# Grep status code from curl output

Tags: shell, curl, grep

My curl output in console is like below. There will be many curl commands in the shell script which i will be looping through "n" times. I would like to capture/grep only those status which are not equal to `200 OK` and pass it to a file. Please suggest me.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Authorization: Bearer 2d141ec6-1ac7-458a-96f3-318af10ae3b9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe curl's output to this awk:

```
awk '$2 != 200'
```

Alternatively you can use this `curl` command to just get status:

```
curl -Is -w "%{http_code}" -A "Chrome" -L "http://domain.com" -o /dev/null
```

---

To write all the URLs with non 200 in output:

```
url='http://domain.com/'
[[ $(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -A "Chrome" -L "$url" -o /dev/null) != 200 ]] && echo "$url"
```

Comment: my curl is like this- for ((i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
curl -i -vs POST -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" -H "Accept:$ACCEPT_HEADER" "http://$BASE_URI/api/$PLATFORM/curated/featured" | awk '$2 != 200' >> RESULT.txt
done >> result1.txt

Comment: This is resulting soo many other stuffs in the RESULT.txt file. I just want to have only status code in that file which is not equal to 200

Comment: In that use my 2nd suggested command that only prints status i.e. 200 or 404.

Comment: This results code 200 for everything, even links that should be 403

Answer (score 1):

The  `-v` option inverts the match

```
$ grep -v "^HTTP/1.1 200"
```